# How to use NATS Streaming Server with Apache flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, nats.io, nats-streaming-server

I want to use NATs streaming server to streaming data and using Flink want to process on data.

how I can use apache flink to process real-time streaming data with NATS streaming server?

Comment: This is super relevant. I'm looking for a Kafka alternative and NATS Streaming would be a good contender if not for the lack of support for tools like Flink. I could find connectors for Spark Streaming and [this](https://github.com/mring33621/nats-messaging-for-flink) for Flink, but it is very old.  Have you looked into Siddhi?

Comment: @monkeyman Have you looked into Apache Pulsar which is a Kafka alternative? It offers a Flink connector.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to either find or develop a Flink/NATS connector, or mirror the data into some other stream storage service that is already has Flink support. There is not a NATS connector among [the connectors that are part of Flink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/), or [Apache Bahir](http://bahir.apache.org/), or in the collection of [Flink community packages](https://flink-packages.org/categories/connectors). But if you search around, you will find some relevant projects on github, etc.

When evaluating a connector implementation, in addition to the usual considerations, consider these factors:

- does it provide both consumer and producer interfaces?
- does it do checkpointing?
- what processing guarantees does it provide? (at least once, exactly once)
- how good is the error handling?
- performance: e.g., is it somehow batching writes?
- how does it handle serialization?
- does it expose any metrics?

If you decide to write your own connector, there are existing connectors for similar systems you can use as a reference, e.g., Nifi, Pulsar, etc. And you should be aware that the interfaces used by data sources are currently being refactored under the umbrella of [FLIP-27](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-27%3A+Refactor+Source+Interface).